# android phone screen isn't enough to display the whole content

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, screen

i'm creating an android app using Xamarin.android. this app is supposed to get data from a database and put them in a listview. now my problem is that the list doesn't fit in the screen.

this is my layout to customize the listview:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/customselector"
   android:padding="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
     android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center"/>
   <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/> 
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/> 

     <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView3"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/> 
       
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView4"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/> 
 
</RelativeLayout >
```

I want the controls to keep the same size. isn't there a way to move the content of the screen to view the rest of it?
thanks in advance

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearLayout` with setting `android:layout_weight="1"` of each `TextView` to keep the same size of each control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

 

    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff00"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 

    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff00"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff00"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot sir. I was working on solving the problem and I finally used the horizontalScrollView. thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that.